# Файлы btw. Что это и с чем их едят

Tags: windows

Здравствуйте вопрос о файлах .btw в интернете нашёл только примеры программ-шуток.
Что собственно это за файлы и как их программировать с их помощью( на каком языке)?

Comment: *Здравствуйте, не знаю какую метку поставить*. [tag:windows], наверно.

Answer (score 1):

Это расширения файла программы BarTender

> What is .btw file?
>
> The BTW file extension is used by BarTender, the world's leading
>   software for designing and printing labels, barcodes and RFID tags,
>   developed and sold by Seagull Scientific. A *.btw file contains
>   Barcode label created and saved in the program.

http://www.file-extensions.org/btw-file-extension

http://fileinfo.com/extension/btw

Comment: Я вообще-то  про исполняемые скрипты для win , а не про сторонние программы.